# Command line grep regex number lower than 100 including floating points. (BRE)

Tags: regex, command-line, grep

I am trying to create a grep regex pattern that would  allow me to get all of the values lower than 100 (including floating points) form the mass(g) column of the below csv file.

**I need to use grep, and preferably the BRE (basic regex pattern) and I cannot use cut to specify the column I am interested in.**

What I have for now is:

,\d{2},|,\d{2}.\d*,

This command does not work in my Ubuntu command line (although it does seem to be correct when I  check it in https://regex101.com/

Can anyone help my to to this with BRE patter?

name,  id,nametype,recclass,mass (g),fall,year,reclat,reclong,GeoLocation

```
Aachen,1,Valid,L5,21,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775; 6.08333)"
Aarhus,2,Valid,H6,720,Fell,01/01/1951 12:00:00 AM,56.183330,10.233330,"(56.18333; 10.23333)"
Abee,6,Valid,EH4,107000,Fell,01/01/1952 12:00:00 AM,54.216670,-113.000000,"(54.21667; -113.0)"
Acapulco,10,Valid,Acapulcoite,1914,Fell,01/01/1976 12:00:00 AM,16.883330,-99.900000,"(16.88333; -99.9)"
```

Comment: Try `grep -o ',[0-9]\{2\}\(\.[0-9]*\)\{0,1\},' file` or `grep -oE '\<[0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]+)?\>' file`

Comment: Why are you restricted to `grep` for parsing a CSV? What is your expected output?

Comment: Will https://ideone.com/6H9riY work for you?

Comment: Hey Wiktor! Thank you very much for the answer! So I guess I need to do it with grep for the sake of learning it's syntax (and losing  some in the proces)                                                                                                   So your regex works, but unfortunately it also matches the lat and long columns.  @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: In the meantime I have came out with this pattern which defines the range of numbers correctly                                                                                                                          
grep "\,[[:digit:]]\{1,2\}\,\|\,[[:digit:]]\{1,2\}\.[[:digit:]]\+\," datosMeteoritos.csv                              but it also matches columns that I am not interested in. Any ideas on hoy to solve this ?

Comment: Longitude and lattitude values *are* float values. You need to limit the number of fractional digits.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/OFFu58

Comment: POSIX sh: `while IFS=, read -r x x x x g x; do case ${g%.*} in [0-9]|[0-9][0-9]) echo $g;; esac; done < file.csv`

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use Bash with a POSIX ERE regex like

```sh
rx=',([0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?),'
while IFS= read -a line; do
  if [[ "$line" =~ $rx ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}";
  fi
done  < file
```

See [this demo](https://ideone.com/8mQeMo). The `,([0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?),` regex matches

- `,` - a comma
- `([0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)` - Group 1:

  - `[0-9]{1,2}` - one or two digits
  - `(\.[0-9]{1,3})?` - an optional Group 2: a dot, one, two or three digits
- `,` - a comma

The `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` fetches the Group 1 value only.

If you need a POSIX BRE solution with `grep` badly, you can use

```sh
while IFS= read -a line; do
  m=$(grep -o ',[0-9]\{1,2\}\(\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\{0,1\},' <<< "$line" | head -n 1)
  echo "${m//,/}"
done  < file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/OFFu58). The regex is the same as POSIX ERE with one capturing group only, used to quantify the `.` and 1-3 fractional digits. The `| head -n 1` is used to extract the first match on a line.

**However**, using `grep` when iterating the lines in a file is not recommended.

Comment: if your grep can only do POSIX BRE (ie. no `-E`), would it have `-o`?